# Dgraph - cannot store emoji

Tags: utf-8, emoji, dgraph

I have an issue when storing emoji in facets in Dgraph database (which store UTF-8 string).

It work fine with some but I get a parse error when reading the value for some others:

```
Unable to marshal response
```

For example:  that has [these](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f96e/index.htm) properties.

I'm writing into dgraph using the Java client and setting the value using `ByteString.copyFromUtf8(val);`

Any idea about why it works well for some emojis and why I get error with some others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was due to the way Dgraph was creating JSON responses for queries, as detailed in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/issues/2662. This is fixed in newer versions of Dgraph (v1.0.12+).

You can try it out with the latest <s>v1.0.12-rc6</s> v1.0.12 version.